# TPK creation failed - ERROR 001117: Map description property must be set Failed to execute

Tags: arcmap, tiles, tile-package

I'm using ArcMap10.6 to make a tile package. I've filled out the description and map title in the map document properties but I get the this error:

```
ERROR 001117: Map description property must be set Failed to execute
```

Which says the description in the map document properties must be populated:

[image]

Any clue why this would be happening?

Comment: Type something in summary box, e.g. initials.

Comment: @FelexP I did and it worked, but only after closing ArcMap and restarting it. I tried it again with just the description and title in another mxd, and again I got the error. I closed and reopened the mxd and then it worked. I think once you populate the map doc properties the application just needs to refresh with those properties already in place. A bug...Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Type in a description as above and simply save the .mxd again then re-run tool.  It will work even if you have left the tool open and all the parameters filled in.